# ebgp in one broadcast network

Tags: routing, bgp

can you help me?
Why vios4 dont change next-hop(ebgp) when it send 3.3.3.3/32 to vios5? On vios5 i see network 3.3.3.3 with next-hop 192.168.1.3

[image]

Comment: You will need to tell us *a lot more* about your network, start with the router details (make, model) and their (sanitized) configs. Check the [help] for how to ask a good question.

Comment: His question is good.  The diagram contains the information needed to understand it.  If you don't have a lot of experience with BGP it could be tough to parse, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to configure a routing policy to rewrite that next-hop if that's the behavior you want.  BGP does not automatically change them when propagating routes in this scenario because of the common LAN.

Since there is a common LAN among the three routers, it actually removes a hop to keep the original next-hop.

Related trivia: on most Internet Exchange / Peering Points, there is a policy requiring members to rewrite next-hop, so they do not *sell next-hop* to others on the exchange.

The specification is [RFC4271 §5.1.3 NEXT_HOP Path Attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#section-5.1.3) rule 2.2, which reads as follows:

> Otherwise, if the route being announced was learned from an external peer, the speaker can use an IP address of any adjacent router (known from the received NEXT_HOP attribute) that the speaker itself uses for local route calculation in
> the NEXT_HOP attribute, provided that peer X shares a common subnet with this address.  This is a second form of "third
> party" NEXT_HOP attribute.

Comment: ok, thank you, can you get me RFC on this question?

Comment: Sure, I added a reference to the spec to my answer.